# iPhone Stylesheet or JS

Tags: iphone, stylesheet

I downloaded a template and customised it a bit. It's working well but the template has a kind of mobile style sheet. When I open the webpage with the iPhone, it looks great on the homepage. However, on the most important pages I don't want it to appear for mobile I want it to appear like it would on a browser.

I've tried.

1. Deleting the: style-mobile.css file. - Nothing happened.
2. Playing around with the style-mobile.css file. - Nothing!
3. Deleting some js files.

I can't seem to find the code that is telling my iPhone to open the page like an iPhone instead of opening it like a browser.

Where will I find this??

Answer (score 0):

The idea that you can download an arbitrary HTML/CSS/JS(?) template that is designed for mobiles and have it magically adapt to look right in a classic browser window is .... naive.

Either look for a template that is *designed* to look good in both contexts, or build your own layouts using something like [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) which is *responsive* to differences in the display port size.